# Why too many partitions on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, windows-10, ubuntu, hard-drive, partitioning

I have just installed Windows 10 (20H2) by partitioning disk as C and D drives and shrink the C drive using Disk Management Tool of Windows for installing Ubuntu. Then I installed Ubuntu and on Windows, I realized that there are too many partitions as seen on the following image:

[image: Disk Management]

Normally Windows was creating just a single recovery partition during installation or disk partitioning, but for my situation I am confused about the following issues:

**1.** I am not sure if the partitions 100 MB (EFI System) and 537 MB (Recovery Partition) are normal or extra. Is EFI System partition related to new Windows version (20H2)?

**2.** Is 537 MB (Recovery Partition) created while installing Linux? I do not remember it after shrinking C drive yesterday, but not sure.

**3.** Can I delete some of these 3 partitions (499 MB, 100 MB, 537 MB)?

Comment: Why do you think there are too many partitions? You can have at least 128 partitions in GPT. Is your problem perhaps actually how the second recovery partition is in the way? // The number of partitions is completely normal and has been that way for many years.

Comment: @Daniel Thnaks, but some partitions seems to be redundant. Do you mean that the first 2 partitions (499 MB, 100 MB) are normal and the last one (537 MB) are not?

Comment: @Daniel Could you please clarify me by replying my questions above?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Are the EFI System and Recovery Partitions normal?**

Yes, both are normal, and are created automatically when you install Windows.
EFI System partition is necessary for your operating systems to run - do not delete it.

**2. Was the second recovery partition created while installing linux?**

<s>Yes, most probably - partitions are usually created "from left to right", so to speak. Since the second recovery partition is located "after" the main Ubuntu partition, this would indicate that it was created when installing Ubuntu.</s>

Take a look at Daniel's comments - apparently, the second partition was made by Windows - presumably after Ubuntu was installed and before partition D: was made.

**3. Can I delete some of these 3 partitions?**

You can try deleting recovery partitions. But deleting the first one might not be as useful as you think, since you won't be able to expand your C drive, for example, without moving the EFI partition to the very beginning of the disk. Deleting the second one will allow you to either expand your Ubuntu partition or your D drive.

Comment: **Perfect explanations**, many thanks!.. I think SO should post this answer as a Best Practice to show users how to answer a question :) Because there are many users who are not able to give answer due to not being able to understand teh questions :)

Comment: On the other hand, just for clarification: Ok I do not touch the first partition related to Windows. But, I am not sure why the second partition is marked primary. Is it related to dual boot?

Comment: And I followed [this](https://smarttechnicalworld.com/how-to-dual-boot-windows-10-and-ubuntu/) site for installing Ubuntu as dual boot. However, the step 7 related to swapping and allocating `/home` directory is not clear. Could you suggest me a proper example for installing Linux without swapping?

Comment: @user1686 I could not understand what do you mean, but could you please tell me how should reinstall Ubuntu to that part again? Should I entirely delete Ubuntu and 527 MB partitions and then merge and format it? Finally install Ubuntu to that merged partition?

Comment: @user1686 Amigo? Where did you go?

Comment: Any help please?

Comment: There are primary, logical, and extended partitions (and maybe some others)? Check that out.
You can always disable swap in linux after it's installed - unless you made a swap partition, but i don't think that's what you did.
And yes, you should format all ubuntu partitions, merge them, and install ubuntu again, if reinstalling is what you want.

Comment: “Was the second recovery partition created while installing linux?” – No, absolutely not. It’s a Windows partition that was created when Windows was installed.

Comment: Thanks. What about the procedures related to allocating home and free space steps? I am very confused with that and if you suggest a better example could you let me know so that I can follow?

Comment: @DanielB how can one confirm that?

Comment: Ok, I will have a look at. I deleted the unnecessary part using `DISKPART` and now I create a new volume for Ubuntu. At this stage, should I assign drive letter or not? C: drive is for Windows, D: drive is for Data. Assigning E drive for Ubuntu operating system does not seems to be good. Instead, Should I assign D to it and swap with Data drive? Or should I not assign a letter?

Comment: @GChuf [This was answered here.](https://superuser.com/q/1210470/219095) So not on installation but upgrade, but whatever.